# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo null object refernce

Tags: java, android, butterknife

I am getting a

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.cygnet.monesmartstore/com.cygnet.mone.views.activities.SplashScreenActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   com.cygnet.mone.views.widgets.ErrorView.setOnRetryListener(com.cygnet.mone.views.widgets.ErrorView$RetryListener)'
>   on a null object reference error

My **activity class** is:

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends BaseScreen implements SplashView, MyOnClick.MyOnClickListener, ErrorView.RetryListener {

private static final String TAG = SplashScreenActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private SplashPresenter mPresenter;
protected MyOnClick myOnClickListener = new MyOnClick();

@BindView(R.id.imgViewSplashLogo)
ImageView imgViewSplashLogo;

@BindView(R.id.errorViewSplash)
ErrorView errorViewSplash;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    errorViewSplash.setOnRetryListener(this);
    mPresenter = new SplashPresenter(this);


   mPresenter.registerBus();

}
```

My **logcat output** is:

```
 2018-10-30 10:41:33.964 451-451/com.cygnet.monesmartstore E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.cygnet.monesmartstore, PID: 451
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cygnet.monesmartstore/com.cygnet.mone.views.activities.SplashScreenActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.cygnet.mone.views.widgets.ErrorView.setOnRetryListener(com.cygnet.mone.views.widgets.ErrorView$RetryListener)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.cygnet.mone.views.widgets.ErrorView.setOnRetryListener(com.cygnet.mone.views.widgets.ErrorView$RetryListener)' on a null object reference
    at com.cygnet.mone.views.activities.SplashScreenActivity.onCreate(SplashScreenActivity.java:81)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
2018-10-30 10:41:33.966 451-451/com.cygnet.monesmartstore E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cygnet.monesmartstore/com.cygnet.mone.views.activities.SplashScreenActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.cygnet.mone.views.widgets.ErrorView.setOnRetryListener(com.cygnet.mone.views.widgets.ErrorView$RetryListener)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.cygnet.mone.views.widgets.ErrorView.setOnRetryListener(com.cygnet.mone.views.widgets.ErrorView$RetryListener)' on a null object reference
    at com.cygnet.mone.views.activities.SplashScreenActivity.onCreate(SplashScreenActivity.java:81)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) '
```

Previously it was working but when I updated my gradle version and dependencies this runtime error has occurred. My guess is this is related to the *jakewarton* library

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: post your code for xml.

Comment: `errorViewSplash` is null. Probably because there is no `ErrorView` with id `errorViewSplash` in your `activity_splash_screen`

Comment: Solved issue my guesses right I added the wrong dependency for butter knife library

Answer (score 0):

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Add this line below

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```